# Converting minutes since midnight to 24-hour time

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I have minutes since midnight.

Eg 3Am is represented as = `180` (found using  `3*60`)

Now I need to convert it into `24` hour time format  `HH24 :mm` =  **03:00**

How can we use simple date formatter/calender for this?

Comment: In which way is this connected to the current date and time in your time zone? Time intervals are better computed without reference to a certain calendar, i.e., the mapping of a point in time to a specific reckoning expressed in y,m,d,h,m,s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use maths, forcing the date time library to do this won't be any simpler (as it expects milli-seconds and time zone)

```
int mins = 180;
String hhmm = String.format("%02d:%02d", mins / 60, mins % 60);
```

---

To do much the same thing with Calendar (which will handle daylight savings you can do)

```
int mins = 180;
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, mins/60);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mins % 60);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
String hhmm = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
System.out.println(hhmm);
```

prints

```
03:00
```

However on the days when daylight savings changes you could get 02:00 or 04:00

Comment: Of course assuming that those minutes after midnight are in the same timezone and ignoring DST.

Comment: Or that today is the day.

Answer (score -1):

The [answer by Peter Lawrey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24983695/642706) is correct, as per usual.

## Joda-Time

My added value is to give an example with an alternative library, [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), as the java.util.Date & .Calendar classes are notoriously troublesome and should be avoided.

## LocalTime

Both Joda-Time and the new [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) in [Java 8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8_.28March_18.2C_2014.29) (inspired by Joda-Time) offer a [`LocalTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalTime.html) class to represent a time-only without any date or time zone. Sounds like this applies to your needs.

Just be *very sure* that you do not need more than LocalTime. If this data is meant to the number of minutes since midnight in Paris, and you might mix in other data that represents date-times in New York or Auckland, then you should be using the [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) class instead of LocalTime. Naïve programmers who think/hope that ignoring time zone makes things simpler are headed for big trouble.

## Example Code

Some example code in Joda-Time 2.4.

```
// Input
int minutes = 180;
int millisecondsSinceAnyMidnight = ( minutes * 60 * 1000 );
LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.fromMillisOfDay( millisecondsSinceAnyMidnight );

// Output
String outputDefault = localTime.toString();
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "HH:mm" );
String outputHHMM = formatter.print( localTime );

// Dump to console.
System.out.println( "outputDefault: " + outputDefault );
System.out.println( "outputHHMM: " + outputHHMM );
```

When run.

```
outputDefault: 03:00:00.000
outputHHMM: 03:00
```